# Can java's servlet filter catch Oracle DB calls and get detailed info from it?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, query-string, servlet-filters

This question is related to my previous question [ [How to get query string from connection in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39883597/how-to-get-query-string-from-connection-in-java) ], if I need to get the details of a Oracle DB call [ query string, time duration for the execution ], can Java's servlet filter catch all that info ? If so, it can make the task a lot easier when there are hundreds of places that make DB calls in a web app.

Comment: What "all that info"? and what do you mean by "task a lot easier where there are hundred....."  what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Nambari : All that info refers to "query string, time duration for the execution". There are hundreds of db calls and I want to catch each db query and execution time. Trying to catch that info from servletfilter, is that possible ?

Comment: If number of queries are limited, may be you could think about storing them in session, isn't it?

Comment: I don't want to modify the code in hundreds of places that db is called, if I can catch them in one or two places that's preferred.

Comment: I don't think you can use a servlet filter for this because it can only intercept HTTP requests that are sent to the application server (not traffic that the app server sends to the db). If you're on Oracle, did you check out the [diagnostic utilities that come with the driver](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/diagnose.htm), or are you using an older version?

Comment: I did try to use it, but got an error message, using 11g, as asked in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981141/how-to-get-name-correctly-in-oracles-diagnosability-in-jdbc

Comment: Ok, Thanks Frank, I'll try to have a look at this in my local environment.